# Is Object Oriented Approach with Graph Theory Algorithms faster in Java than general array based manipulations?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, graph-theory

I always have a habit of creating lots of classes while solving Graph Theory problems like :

```
class Node{
   ......
}
class Edge{
   ......
}
```

Often this runs me into performance and speed issues. Hence I feel that using arrays for storing graphs is faster than storing it in User Defined Classes and Structures like Lists and Maps though the latter provides more flexibility and readability to the code. Hence do the use of arrays and language structures for representing graphs really cause any significant performance boost. If yes, which should be the general choice while coding in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Measure it.

Build a solution, put it into a profiler and look where most of the computation time is used up. You cannot sensibly argue about this topic in general, you need experiments.

That said: In 98% of the cases, you are better of with writing readable OO code. If it turns out to be too slow, narrow down the method that causes the trouble (with a profiler) and try to make *that method* faster. Don't start writing ugly code in the hope that it might faster than nice one.

Comment: I have tried to measure it many times using a profiler but often end up with micro benchmarking. I cannot figure out the least input needed to differentiate between the running time of both the approaches.

Comment: If you don't see significant differences, why bother? Just take the OO approach.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with arrays is that they suppose a huge waste of memory for big graphs, which usually implement few links between nodes.

The performance boost you would get would depend not only on the data structure, but also on the type of graph and operations you perform on it.

E.g. deleting a node could be very expensive on an array implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Well yes , sometimes graphs are faster then array. Basically Sometimes it's depend on your requirement. Sometimes if you use array is best choice and some times graphs. There are many collections are available in java. like linkedlist , arraylist , vector , doublelinkedlist etc. All the collections are fast in java. You just have to choose the best possibilities matched with your requirement...